# Swap Continuous Webjob in Azure production to staging slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

Let's say I have a webapp in Azure that auto deploys a continuous webjob.  This webapp also has a `production` and `staging` slot, and the site deploys to `staging`, after which a swap happens (manually or automatic) to move the latest into the `production` slot.

Further, let's assume that the `production` webjob is running and processing and generally doing it's job before the swap begins. When the deployment to `staging` happens, the latest webjob does not start because of the `WEBJOBS_STOPPED = 1` configuration setting that is honored.

However, after the swap completes, does the webjob that was previously in `production` and now is in `staging` continue running?  If not, how does it stop? When does it stop? When does the `WEBJOBS_STOPPED` flag begin to be honored when a running webjob is moved from a `production` slot to a `staging slot`?

I can't have the two webjobs running at the same time and it's unclear what the behavior around a swap is... Continuous singletons are easy using the `is_singleton` property in the webjob settings, but ***"vertical"*** webjobs running at the same time around a swap doesn't appear to be clearly understood or documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to make `WEBJOBS_STOPPED=1` a slot setting on Staging, so that it is always set for the Staging and never for Production. This will guarantee that you don't have both running at the same time (other than potentially for a few seconds during swap transition).

See [this post](http://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/) for some deeper information on how swapping works.

Comment: thanks! Slot settings are fairly straight forward, but when is it honored? If a currently running production webjob is half way through it's 5 minutes of processing when a swap is completed, does the webjob just somehow immediately stop in the staging slot when the swap is complete, or does it keep running? And since it's continuous, won't it just run forever in the staging slot?

Comment: As part of the swap, both slots get restarted. That can indeed cause some very long processing to get aborted.

Comment: Here's an example of how to configure slot settings in json ARM templates for anyone interested: [https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-app-service-resource-templates-tips-tricks/](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-app-service-resource-templates-tips-tricks/)